# Finding Plus Sign in Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var string = 'abcd+1';
var pattern = 'd+1'
var reg = new RegExp(pattern,'');
alert(string.search(reg));
```

I found out last night that if you try and find a plus sign in a string of text with a Javascript regular expression, it fails.  It will not find that pattern, even though it exists in that string.  This has to be because of a special character.  What's the best way to find a plus sign in a piece of text?  Also, what other characters will this fail on?

Comment: Easy way to make it : `" [\+] "` this is the alphabet. You may want all plus signs, then `" [\+]* "`.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Plus is [a special character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) in regular expressions, so to express the character as data you must escape it by prefixing it with `\`.

```
var reg = /d\+1/;
```

Answer (score 28):

```
\-\.\/\[\]\\ **always** need escaping
\*\+\?\)\{\}\| need escaping when **not** in a character class- [a-z*+{}()?]
```

But if you are unsure, it does no harm to include the escape before a non-word character you are trying to match.

A digit or letter is a word character, escaping a digit refers to a previous match, escaping a letter  can match an unprintable character, like a newline (\n), tab (\t) or word boundary (\b), or a a set of characters, like any word-character (\w), any non-word character (\W).

Don't escape a letter or digit unless you mean it.

Comment: @Tomalak: [^A-Za-z0-9_] https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: +1 (no pun intended) for mentioning character classes

Answer (score 20):

Just a note,

`\` should be `\\` in RegExp pattern string, `RegExp("d\+1")` will not work and `Regexp(/d\+1/)` will get error.

```
var string = 'abcd+1';
var pattern = 'd\\+1'
var reg = new RegExp(pattern,'');
alert(string.search(reg));
//3
```

Comment: will this work within a character group such as `[A-Z\\+]`?

Comment: Thank you, YOU! :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use the escape character \ in front of the + in your pattern.  eg.  \+

Comment: Not when constructing a RegEx from a string. "\+" is the same as "+", it would have to be "\\+".

Comment: @David, do you mean in C# for example?  In that case I normally use the @ verbatim string character to avoid too many \\\\\\ symbols ;)

Comment: @Ash: No. For example, var pattern = new RegExp("(\\d+)\\s*\\+\\s*(\\d+)"); is equivalent to var pattern = /(\d+)\s*\+\s*(\d+)/;

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to escape the plus sign:

```
var pattern = /d\+1/
```

The plus sign is used in regular expressions to indicate 1 or more characters in a row.

Comment: Nope, either remove your quotes around the pattern to make it a real RegExp object, or add an additional backslash before your backslash. Backslash indicates the start of an escape sequence in JavaScript strings.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `var pattern = '/d\\+1/'`.

The string will escape `'\\'` as `'\'` (`'\\+'` --> `'\+'`) so the regex object init with `/d\+1/`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use `+ (plus sign)` or `$ (sigil /dollar sign)`, then use `\ (backslash)` as a prefix. Like that:
`\$` or `\+`