# Replacing + with plus using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a text that contains:

```
var str = 'Coins ++';
```

I need to replace it with 'Coins plusplus'

The following doesn't work:

```
str = str.replace(/+/g , "plus");
```

How to get this done?

Comment: You need to escape `+` using \ like `str.replace(/\+/g, "plus")`

Comment: `+` is a special character in RegExp patterns, being [a shorthand for a `{1,}` (one or more) quantifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#quantifiers).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace all plus signs (+) with space in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822445/replace-all-plus-signs-with-space-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` is a special character when used inside of regex, you need to escape it by adding `\` in front of it to make regex recognize it as a string.

```js
var str = 'Coins ++';

console.log(str.replace(/\+/g, "plus"));
```

Answer (score 5):

use with `\` before the plus. because `+` is one [of the special character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021053/finding-plus-sign-in-regular-expression) of the regex

```js
var str = 'Coins ++';

str = str.replace(/\+/g, "plus");
console.log(str)
```