# find all documents where it matches a query and the query is a value inside a reference field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

im trying to ruturn all the data in my Orders schema where it matches one of the receiver/sender/driver.phoneNumber field in Orders schema, my Orders schema has those fields as a refernce to Users schema, my issue is when I search for a phoneNumber I want it to be regex, so that means it will return an array of documents, so its not a single value in order for me to query it inside the order document, my code is

```
else if (searchQuery) {
if (searchQuery.startsWith("07")) {
  const num = "+964" + searchQuery.substring(1);
  const users = await Register.find({            //this will return all users whom phoneNumber start with the query number
    phoneNumber: { $regex: num },
  });
  orders = await Orders.find({
    $or: [
      { receiverId: users },         //this query is obviously wrong, but im trying to implement something like this, 
      { driverId: users },
      { senderId: users },
    ],

    ...branches,
  })
    .limit(limit)
    .skip(skip)

    .populate("receiverId")
    .populate("driverId")
     .populate("senderId")
```

how to return all the order documents where it matches the array of possible users?
thanks,

Comment: can you show the data format returning from `Register` and `Orders` collections?

Comment: order:  receiverId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Register",
    },
    driverId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Register",
    },
    senderId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Register",
    },

Comment: fullName: {
      type: String,
    },
    phoneNumber: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "phone number is required"],
      unique: [true, "this phone number has been used before"],
    },

Comment: and just posted relevant fields btw, @TalESid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I understand from your question and comments is that you need to
> fetch out users with matching `phoneNumber` regex and then from
> `Order` schema, get all orders having either `receiverId`, `driverId`
> or `senderId` in those users array.

To achieve this, let's first fetch users (only `_id`s) as an array.

```
const user_ids = await Register
.find({ phoneNumber: { $regex: num } })
.distinct('_id');
// This will return only distinct "_id" of users as an array (not an array of objects)
```

Now, filter out orders using these ids

```
const orders = await Order
.find({
    // the following code means orders where either receiver/driver/sender's id is "IN" the user_ids array, fetched above
    $or: [
        {receiverId: {$in: user_ids}},
        {driverId: {$in: user_ids}},
        {senderId: {$in: user_ids}}
    ],

    ...branches
})

.populate("receiverId")
.populate("driverId")
.populate("senderId")

.limit(limit)
.skip(skip);
```

Here is your query (according to my understanding )

Comment: thanks man its what I wanted, I just had a little issue with the num variable I did add a "+964" country code as a prefix to it, it wouldnt execute that line where u find the user_ids, turns out it was that + sign inside the string, its kinda weird, but doesnt matter it works all good now haha :)

Comment: Its because of regex. 'Plus' sign is special character in regex, so you need to escape it like `\+`. Your `num` should start with `'\+964'` to match regex.
See this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/2021067/7109362